# Slicing a list from csv.reader

Tags: python, slice

I'm new to Python so please be patient. I'm trying to extract the first 10 characters of each item in a list using slice. The list is from a csv.reader function. Slice seems to behave differently when I use it on a list from csv.reader vs a list I create in the code.
My list `timesheet.csv` contains these values:

```
20/10/2015 09:10
20/10/2015 10:20
20/10/2015 16:30
21/10/2015 08:30
21/10/2015 09:45
21/10/2015 10:22
21/10/2015 14:01
```

I'm trying to delete the time to leave only the dates. So I thought the below code should do it:

```
import csv
with open('timesheet.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    your_list = list(reader)
    for x in your_list:
        current_date = x[:10]
        print(current_date)
```

I had expected it to output:

```
20/10/2015
20/10/2015
20/10/2015
21/10/2015
21/10/2015
21/10/2015
21/10/2015
```

But instead I get the whole list:

```
20/10/2015 09:10
20/10/2015 10:20
20/10/2015 16:30
21/10/2015 08:30
21/10/2015 09:45
21/10/2015 10:22
21/10/2015 14:01
```

The strange thing is, if I test by adding the list a different way e.g.

```
your_list = ['21/10/2015 16:14', '20/10/2015 23:00']
for x in your_list:
current_date = x[:10]
print(current_date)
```

the output is as how I want it:

```
21/10/2015
20/10/2015
```

I think it has something to do with slice trimming the number of items within a list item rather than characters, but I can't quite figure out why?
Thanks

Comment: indent `current_date = x[:10]` correctly under the `for` loop it belongs to

Comment: Try printing `x`, you'll see that it is a list. You may want `x[0][:10]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the items in `your_list` are lists containing strings, not strings.

Try:

```
for x in your_list:
    current_date = x[0][:10]
    print current_date
```

This should do what you want.  `x[0]` is the string contained within the list that is `x`.

Note, an alternative approach uses pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('timesheet.csv', header=None)
for xx in pd.DatetimeIndex(df[0]):
    print xx.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you. Does csv.reader always return a list of lists? Or could it just be the way my .csv is formatted?

Comment: Each row of the csv file is represented as a list of the (comma-separated) items on that row.  I find pandas's API more intuitive — see the edit to my answer above.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `your_list` is a list of list. To fix your issue, change `current_date = x[:10]` to `current_date = x[0][:10]` and it will be good.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
with open("your_file") as f:
    for line in f:
        print line.split()[0]
        #or print line[:10]  if you want to use slicing approach
```